# Change output URL Search module

Tags: search, urls

I am in need of what i think is, a quick fix.

i am making a wordpress website with divi,
i would like to be able to use this website to search items in an ( i think ) magento webshop. now i dont need to search the database or anything. I would just like to change the output URL of the wordpress/divi search Module. now it would be: cmwb.websites.xs4all.nl/?s=example

i manage to grab this HTML form:

which changes the search output to:

website/?search%3Ffilter ... 3D=tshirts

BUT what i would like is that it would change the output similiar to what it looks like when i use the search module on the webshop ( www.promotex.nl )

which is :

website/search?filter=Fi ... %3Dtshirts

idealy, i would like the standard search module to search the webshop, if it too much work for you guys to change the output URL of it, the HTML code i grabbed would be perfectly fine too.

thanks!

Mart Oosterman

Answer (score 0):

Use `action = 'website/search'` to get the query appended... Ideally your form would look like this...

```
<form action="website/search">
  <input type="text" name="filter" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then you can grab `filter` to interact with Wordpress Query and display result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, Cant post the urls.

could u check this out ? wrote it down on the homepage.

http://cmwb.websites.xs4all.nl/

thanks alot already :)

Comment: Couldn't get you @MartOosterman

Comment: sorry, pretty much a complete noob at this, how would i make the "filter" ineract with the Wordpress Query? and how would i make this search another website ? 

bassicly i would like to change the output of the search to a different website. the search widget would be one [ website1.com ] and it would have to search [ website2.com ] but the search on website 2 has different query's. website 1 would be cmwb.websites.xs4all.n & website 2 www.promotex.nl

Comment: allright, i am using this now :

<form action="http://www.promotex.nl/search?">
  <input type="text" name="FilterForm%5Bname%5D%3D" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>

which returns this URL : 
http://www.promotex.nl/search?FilterForm%255Bname%255D%253D=aansteker    ( the search being "aansteker" ) 

and i would need it to return this URL :

http://www.promotex.nl/search?filter=FilterForm%5Bname%5D%3Daansteker

feel like im getting close,
thanks !

Comment: Sorry for being late... [check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523881/how-do-i-modify-search-query-in-wordpress) this to understand how you will be able to alter the search query...

Comment: I expect that you must be having `search.php` template already.

Comment: Nope, my theme doesnt come with a search.php. gonna read the link you send me, thanks alot!